# Given a DateTimeZone and two Instants, determine if a LocalTime falls between the two Instants

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, nodatime

For each of my users, I store a `tzid` which I convert to a `DateTimeZone` holding information about their local time zone.

I want to send the user a daily email at 8 AM local time; if 8 AM is ambiguous for whatever reason like a daylight savings shift, I just need to pick one of the 8 AM; I don't care which.

My job runs hourly, and I have an `Instant` containing the last run time of the job, and another `Instant` containing the next run time of the job.

Given these two `Instant` called `previousRun` and `nextRun`, and the `DateTimeZone` called `tz` how would I determine whether the `localTime` called `eightAM` falls between the bounds of this job run? If it does, I need to send the user an email.

Comment: @Ben: That's a lot easier to say than to do. The tricky bit is handling things like 8am occurring twice, or being skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given these two Instant called previousRun and nextRun, and the DateTimeZone called tz how would I determine whether the localTime called eightAM falls between the bounds of this job run?

Doing this in a general way is somewhat tricky, I think. However, *if* you can rely on the time you want being well away from midnight *and* your job will run every hour (so you don't need to consider what happens if it hasn't run between midnight and 8am, for example) I think you could do something like this:

```
public static bool ShouldSendEmail(Instant previousRun, Instant nextRun,
                                   DateTimeZone zone)
{
    // Find the instant at which we should send the email for the day containing
    // the last run.
    LocalDate date = previousRun.InZone(zone).Date;
    LocalDateTime dateTime = date + new LocalTime(8, 0);
    Instant instant = dateTime.InZoneLeniently(zone).ToInstant();

    // Check whether that's between the last instant and the next one.
    return previousRun <= instant && instant < nextRun;
}
```

You can check the docs for `InZoneLeniently` to check exactly what result it will give, but it sounds like you don't really mind: this will still send exactly one email a day, in an hour which contains 8am.

I *haven't* parameterized this by the time of day precisely because it would be much harder to handle the general case where the time of day could be near midnight.

EDIT: If you can store the "next date to send" then it's easy - and you don't need the `previousRun` part:

```
public static bool ShouldSendEmail(LocalDateTime nextDate, Instant nextRun,
                                   DateTimeZone zone, LocalTime timeOfDay)
{
    LocalDateTime nextEmailLocal = nextDate + timeOfDay;
    Instant nextEmailInstant =  nextDateTime.InZoneLeniently(zone).ToInstant();
    return nextRun > nextEmailInstant;
}
```

Basically that says, "Work out when we next want to send an email - and if the next run will be later than that, we should send it now."

Comment: Unfortunately, I did simplify a bit. For version one, we send to all users at 8 AM in their local time, but in version two of the feature, I need to let them configure what time they want the email sent.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: How easy would it be to store the local date for which you last sent an email? That would make life easier from the perspective of when next to send, I think...

Comment: Its trivial to store the information; are you using it to eliminate the possible repeat of a time (and thus duplicate email) on a day when that happens?

Comment: As an aside, I can't find any method named `Contains` on `Interval`, nor can I find any differently-named methods that might do the same thing.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: Ah, sorry - that's being introduced in 1.2. Will edit to remove the dependency on that. And yes, storing the last date - or, equivalently, the next date - just makes it easier to predict when to send.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: Edited with an alternative signature if you can store the next date.